# need helpwith listview and data pagers, ajax call concern

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, listview, telerik

I have a page that is being loaded through ajax. In that page that is being called its a listview that is brought to the site that called it. Before I continue developing, can I page through this listview even though it was loaded via ajax from another page?